# Adding custom attribute to SQL DB using dynamic parameter in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I have a CSV file that I need to ingest in MS SQL DB using ADF V2. Now thats a simple thing to achieve and i am able to do it. But I each file also has a Asset ID  associated with it which is dynamically generated you can think of it as a GUID.

Hence essentially, it is there so that in future I have a way to associate which record belong to which CSV as there can be multiple CSVs ingested.

I am able to retrieve the asset ID in form of dynamic parameter till Pipeline but I am not able to add it to the database. Essentially there will be one additional column called assetID against each record in DB. But how to populate it with the dynamic parameter, I am not able to find a way. Can any body help? or if there is any other way to associate a Unique ID to those records of file in DB.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to go about this :

1. For each iteration(single csv file), use a Custom activity, read the csv file, use the pipeline parameter for the attribute you want to add and add it to the DB and then write the record to the table.
2. You can use a Stored Procedure activity and pass the parameter as shown in the below screenshot to add the column that you want to.

[image]

Hope this helps.